# O que está errado no meu código?Sou iniciante

Tags: java

Quero Criar uma classe funcionário com as especificações abaixo, porém não consigo fazer retornar o método mostrar dados e o método calcular salário.
Dá erros de compilação na hora de chamar os métodos, queria saber como posso definir a chamada deles, pois tem algo errado. Desde já muito obrigado.

> O funcionário deve ter:
>
> - Nome, idade, salário por hora e horas trabalhadas no mês.
> - Os atributos da classe devem estar encapsulados.
> - devem existir métodos getters pra todos e setters para salário por hora e horas trabalhadas no mês.
> - Existe uma regra de que o salário por hora deve estar entre 10 e 200.
> - Existe uma regra de que as horas trabalhadas no mês não podem exceder 160 horas.
> - o método `mostrarDados()` é usado para exibir todas as informações do funcionário no console.
> - o método `calcularSalario()` retorna o valor do salário do funcionário. Este montante é obtido através da multiplicação do salário por hora do funcionário e das horas trabalhadas no mês.

Classe `Funcionario`:

```
public class Funcionario {

      private String        nome;
      private int          idade;
      private int   salario_Hora;
      private int horas_trab_mes;


    public double getSalario_Hora() {
        return salario_Hora;
    }
    public void setSalario_Hora(double salario_Hora) {
        if (salario_Hora>10 & salario_Hora<=200){
            this.salario_Hora = salario_Hora;
        }

    }
    public double getHoras_trab_mes() {
        if (horas_trab_mes<=160){
            return horas_trab_mes;  
        }

    }
    public void setHoras_trab_mes(double horas_trab_mes) {
        this.horas_trab_mes = horas_trab_mes;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void mostrarDados(){
        System.out.println("O nome do funcionário é"+getNome());
        System.out.println("A idade do funcionário é"+getIdade);
        System.out.println("O número de horas trabalhadas do funcionário é "+horas_trab_mes);
        System.out.println("O salário por hora do funcionário é"+salario_Hora);
        }

    private double calcularSalario(){
        return salario_Hora*horas_trab_mes;
    }


}
```

Classe `Aplicacao`:

```
public class Aplicacao {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Funcionario f= new Funcionario();
        f.setHoras_trab_mes(100);
        f.setSalario_Hora(100);

        System.out.println("Os dados do funcionário são:"+ f.mostrarDados();
        System.out.println("O salário do funcionário é:"+ f.calcularSalario();

        }
    }
}
```

Ao tentar compilar, obtenho os seguintes erros:

```
C:\Projetos\Funcionario\src\Aplicacao.java:9: error: ')' expected
        System.out.println("Os dados do funcionário são:"+ f.mostrarDados();
C:\Projetos\Funcionario\src\Aplicacao.java:10: error: ')' expected
        System.out.println("O salário do funcionário é:"+ f.calcularSalario();
C:\Projetos\Funcionario\src\Aplicacao.java:14: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
3 errors
```

```
C:\Projetos\Funcionario\src\Funcionario.java:14: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
            this.salario_Hora = salario_Hora;
C:\Projetos\Funcionario\src\Funcionario.java:25: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
        this.horas_trab_mes = horas_trab_mes;
C:\Projetos\Funcionario\src\Funcionario.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("A idade do funcionário é"+getIdade);
  symbol:   variable getIdade
  location: class Funcionario
3 errors
```

Comment: Onde está o problema? Qual resultado você teve e qual era o esperado?

Comment: Em primeiro lugar Bem Vindo, nossa comunidade não é um puzzle de jogo dos 7 erros, também não estamos aqui para resolver exercícios de curso/faculdade huahuahua :-), por favor seja o mais claro possível, qual é o erro apresentado pela sua aplicação ?

Comment: Na verdade não sou da área de TI, mas gosto da idéia de programar, estou fazendo webinario e esse exercício ta na lista , o que é pra fazer ta na descrição do exercício, queria saber se existe algum erro estrutural, conceitual no meu código, sabem me dizer? se puderem me ajudar ficaria grato, não vale nada não isso. Só por lazer mesmo. Abraços.

Comment: Thiago, mesmo sendo pra lazer, não tem problema, desde que ao menos explique o que deu de errado ou não saiu como esperado. Onde vai usar o código é um detalhe, mas a objetividade é importante, até em respeito do tempo de quem vai te ajudar. Aqui tem umas dicas legais: [Ask]. Lembre-se que você pode [edit] a postagem e melhorá-la a qualquer momento.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas Bacco.

Comment: Droga, a pergunta foi fechada e eu estava redigindo uma resposta. Discordo do motivo de fechamento, pois basta dar uma olhada rápida no código que os problemas são facilmente percebidos e se tratam de erros de compilação. Há também problemas referentes ao estilo adotado na codificação. Concordo que esta pergunta está bem longe de ser uma das nossas melhores perguntas, mas não acho que o fechamento se justifique. Votei para reabrir.

Comment: Eu alterei, não ficou suficientemente claro o que eu pergunto?Desculpe não saber perguntar tecnicamente, como foi dito anteriormente, não sou da área. Onde vocês acham que devo melhorar a pergunta? Me ajudem por favor.

Comment: @Bacco Podemos reabrir a pergunta? Se não, gostaria de entender o motivo. Ela me parece estar clara o suficiente.

Comment: @ederwander O programa apresenta diversos erros de compilação bobos, coisa típica de iniciante. Estando isso esclarecido, podemos reabrir a pergunta?

Comment: @VictorStafusa pra mim o problema é amplitude, e não clareza, mas se vc for postar a solução completa, podemos. Avise quando estiver pronta que eu participo da reabertura. Tendo gente disposta a fazer, não sou eu quem vai impedir.

Comment: Obrigado ederwander e VictorStafusa.

Comment: @VictorStafusa a pergunta precisa ser editada e demonstrar os erros, nem todos aqui tem tempo de copiar todo o código na pergunta e ficar verificando os erros existentes um a um, você me entende ?

Comment: @VictorStafusa votei reabertura e sinalizei pra moderação reabrir se quiser, já que vc tem resposta, mas que fique claro para o autor que é liberalidade sua ajudar, e não um "conte com isso sempre".

Comment: @Bacco Certo. Muito obrigado. Trabalhando aqui para evitar o problema [*no soup for you*](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/741.php), ainda mais para quem é iniciante.

Comment: @VictorStafusa as orientações pro autor não foram no sentido de _no soup for you_, foram justamente para viabilizar a ajuda. Se fosse só pra deixar ele na mão, não teria orientado ele a descrever melhor os problemas enfrentados. Nem sempre as pessoas vão ter o tempo necessário para pegar o código, analisar e compilar, e para avaliar a sua resposta complica, pois é um exercício de fé. Não sei se resolveu mesmo, não sei se foram enfrentados todos os problemas, não sei se um próximo visitante vai conseguir entender, e assim vai. Mas votei reabrir pra não deixar o autor na mão.

Comment: Obrigado galera, desculpa o incômodo , não era a intenção importunar ninguém. Obrigado a todos que ajudaram.

Comment: ThiagoMarques não é importuno não, só estamos "brigando" para ajudar de formas diferentes. Eu prefiro que você aprenda a pescar, pq nao teria o peixe pra te dar pronto, mas tá cheio de peixe na comunidade. O @VictorStafusa teve a boa vontade de pescar, limpar o peixe, cozinhar e servir (não sei se ficou bom ou não pq eu não como peixe). O que eu sugeriria é saborear o tal peixe, mas sem deixar de aprender a pescar nas próximas.

Comment: Marquei o verdinho pro Victor já, ele mereceu!, mandou muito bem, eu até entendo a sua analogia do aprender a pescar, não me nego a aprender a pescar, mas como hoje em dia existem facilitadores pra pescar, já que eles existem e são solidários, porque não facilitar o aprendizado? antes pra aprender a pescar tinhamos que atravessar limitações espaciais e físicas, hoje em dia os peixes pulam na isca :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloquei a descrição dos erros de compilação mais óbvios em comentários:

```java
public class Aplicacao {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Funcionario f= new Funcionario();
        f.setHoras_trab_mes(100);
        f.setSalario_Hora(100);

        // Faltou um fecha parênteses.    
        System.out.println("Os dados do funcionário são:"+ f.mostrarDados();

        // Faltou um fecha parênteses.
        System.out.println("O salário do funcionário é:"+ f.calcularSalario();

        // Você está abrindo duas chaves e fechando três.
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class Funcionario {

      private String        nome;
      private int          idade;
      private int   salario_Hora;
      private int horas_trab_mes;


    public double getSalario_Hora() {
        return salario_Hora;
    }
    public void setSalario_Hora(double salario_Hora) {
        if (salario_Hora>10 & salario_Hora<=200){
            // O atributo salario_Hora é int, enquanto que você está tentando
            // atribuir-lhe um double. A linguagem java não permite isso diretamente
            // sem um cast porque iria perder precisão. Afinal como você colocaria
            // um número fracionário em algo que só aceita inteiros sem fazer
            // nenhuma conversão, adaptação ou arredondamento?
            this.salario_Hora = salario_Hora;
        }

    }
    public double getHoras_trab_mes() {
        if (horas_trab_mes<=160){
            return horas_trab_mes;  
        }

    }
    public void setHoras_trab_mes(double horas_trab_mes) {
        // Novamente, tentando colocar double no int.
        this.horas_trab_mes = horas_trab_mes;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void mostrarDados(){
        System.out.println("O nome do funcionário é"+getNome());

        // getIdade é um método, então faltou os parênteses.
        System.out.println("A idade do funcionário é"+getIdade);
        System.out.println("O número de horas trabalhadas do funcionário é "+horas_trab_mes);
        System.out.println("O salário por hora do funcionário é"+salario_Hora);
        }

    private double calcularSalario(){
        // Aqui você havia esquecido o ponto-e-vírgula,
        // mas você já editou isso na pergunta.
        return salario_Hora*horas_trab_mes;
    }


}
```

A maioria desses erros de compilação é simples de se resolver, então deixo para você. Quanto ao problema de colocar `double` no `int`, é só você decidir de uma vez por todas se o atributo é `double` ou `int` e fazer os parãmetros do setter e o valor de retorno do getter refletir a sua escolha.

Por fim, ainda há outros problemas acerca de estilo de codificação. As convenções de nomenclatura ditam que nomes de métodos, atributos e variáveis locaias devem ser compostos por palavras concatenadas sem espaços, sendo a primeira letra de cada palavra minúscula e todas as demais minúsculas, com exceção da primeira letra que deve ser sempre minúscula. Assim sendo, esses identificadores estão com uma nomenclatura boa:

- `nome`
- `idade`
- `getNome`
- `getIdade`
- `calcularSalario`

Já estes têm uma nomenclatura ruim:

- `salario_Hora`: Deveria ser `salarioHora`
- `horas_trab_mes`: Deveria ser `horasTrabalhadasMes` - Não abrevie palavras se você não tiver um excelente motivo para isso.
- `getSalario_Hora`: Deveria ser `getSalarioHora`
- `setSalario_Hora`: Deveria ser `setSalarioHora`
- `getHoras_trab_mes`: Deveria ser `getHorasTrabalhadasMes`
- `setHoras_trab_mes`: Deveria ser `setHorasTrabalhadasMes`

Feito isso, agora ainda haverá alguns outros errinhos de compilação mais complicadinhos, aqui vão eles:

```
    public double getHoras_trab_mes() {
        if (horas_trab_mes<=160){
            return horas_trab_mes;  
        }

    }
```

Se o número de horas trabalhadas for menor ou igual a 160, ele será retornado. Mas, e se não for? A resposta é que este método está errado e ele deveria retornar o valor independente de qualquer coisa, o `if` é desnecessário.

O método `mostrarDados` é `void`. Ou seja, ele não produz resultado. Ele mesmo está mostrando a saída por meio do `System.out.println` ao invés de devolver algum valor. Esse comportamento é incompatível com o que há na sua classe `Aplicacao`:

```
    System.out.println("Os dados do funcionário são:"+ f.mostrarDados();
```

Ao invés disso, basta chamar o `mostrarDados()` diretamente e ele mesmo cuidará da tarefa de mostrar os dados:

```
    f.mostrarDados();
```

E se você já tem um método para mostrar os dados, então você não precisa fazer isso depois:

```
    System.out.println("O salário do funcionário é:"+ f.calcularSalario();
```

Afinal de contas, se você tem um método que serve para mostrar os dados no console, faz mais sentido colocar isso lá dentro.

Com isso, só faltam essas duas regras:

> - Existe uma regra de que o salário por hora deve estar entre 10 e 200.
> - Existe uma regra de que as horas trabalhadas no mês não podem exceder 160 horas.

E você está no caminho certo, o ideal é fazer isso dentro dos setters. Quando estas restrições estão satisfeitas, é fácil, basta setar o valor dos campos e pronto. Quando não são satisfeitas, você pode fazer três possíveis caminhos:

- Não fazer nada - que é o que você está fazendo no momento.
- Escrever algo no `System.out.println` dizendo que o método recusou setar o valor.
- Lançar uma exceção - o que é o tratamento adequado para sistemas robustos, mas você está em um nível iniciante demais para poder lidar com este caso, vez que tratamento de exceções é algo que está em um nível significativamente mais avançado do que o que você está no momento.

Espero ter lhe ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado Victor, esclareceu bastante coisa. Valeu mesmo pela ajuda, acho que o pessoal não gosta muito de quem ta iniciando, não sei...., Abraços.

Comment: @ThiagoMarques Bem, se a minha resposta te ajudou e resolveu o seu problema, marque-a como aceita ao clicar no V verde que está logo embaixo do número da votação. Caso ainda tenha alguma dúvida, ou ache que falta algo importante, poste um comentário. Quanto à comunidade não gostar de iniciantes, isso é uma meia-verdade. Na verdade, a comunidade não gosta é de perguntas com alguns tipos de problemas em sua elaboração que possam dificultar a produção de respostas, ocorre que iniciantes ainda não têm a experiência necessária para elaborar perguntas que não possuam tais problemas.

Comment: Ta la o verdinho Victor!, muito bom comentário, pois é inerente ao status de iniciante essa condição de elaborar perguntas perfeitas é um tanto complicado, obrigado pela empatia. Caso precise de ajuda em estatística, estamos ae :) , abraços!.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Os dados do funcionário são:"+ f.mostrarDados());
System.out.println("O salário do funcionário é:"+ f.calcularSalario());
```

De uma olhada, tem muitas chamadas incompletas, ; faltando verifique ai ...

Comment: Obrigado John-Jones.Vou verificar, abraços.